# Coordinates not aligning accurately with basemap in ggmap with ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2, mapping, ggmap

I have been searching all over and have been unable to solve this problem so please forgive me if it has been asked before.

I have a dataframe that contains coordinate data that is accurate, however when I plot the coordinates in ggmap, they do not line up with coastlines as they should. Some of the points are way offshore or inland which is incorrect (these are sites of rocky reefs in coastal areas). These coordinates were collected in WGS84 format and are accurate. Is there a way to change the coordinate system in ggmap to match up or is there something I have missed?

Note that my lat and long variables are 'SiteLat' and 'SiteLong' within a dataframe labeled 'DF.map'. I colour the points by a factor in my dataframe called 'Ecoregion'.

The code I am using is the following:

```
#create base map for area
GeoBounds <- c(left = min(DF.map$SiteLong)-1, bottom = 
min(DF.map$SiteLat)-1, right = max(DF.map$SiteLong)+1, top = 
max(DF.map$SiteLat)+1)
BaseMap <- get_stamenmap(GeoBounds, zoom = 5, maptype = "toner-lite")
ggmap(BaseMap)

#choose a scale value for the map
scale_value <- 1

#plot site location data onto the map by ecoregion for region boundaries
DataMap <- ggmap(BaseMap) +  
geom_point(data = DF.map, aes(SiteLong, SiteLat, colour = Ecoregion))+
coord_fixed(ratio = 1)+
theme(legend.position = "right", 
    axis.text = element_text(size = 8 * scale_value, colour = "black"),
    legend.text = element_text(size = 8 * scale_value),
    legend.title = element_text(size = 8, face = "bold")
)

DataMap
```

Click link for the resulting map:
[Output map](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YdYL3.png)

```
Ecoregion   SiteCode    SiteLong    SiteLat
Cape Howe   KG-S13  147.3012238 -39.44477844
Cape Howe   KG-S12  147.30203   -39.449
Cape Howe   KG-S4   147.2946625 -39.46456909
Cape Howe   KG-S17  147.2870789 -39.46530151
Cape Howe   KG-S16  147.3515778 -39.47373962
Cape Howe   KG-S15  147.3421478 -39.49295044
Cape Howe   KG-S7   147.3305359 -39.49496079
Cape Howe   TAS78   147.86898   -40.00071
Cape Howe   TAS77   147.8771    -40.00372
Cape Howe   TAS76   147.86694   -40.01106
Cape Howe   TAS75   147.77708   -40.02269
Cape Howe   TAS74   147.84676   -40.02387
Cape Howe   TAS73   147.8423    -40.02462
Cape Howe   TAS72   147.8324    -40.04006
Cape Howe   TAS71   147.75108   -40.05788
Cape Howe   TAS70   147.76598   -40.08227
Cape Howe   TAS69   147.75906   -40.09146
Bassian PPB21   144.91274   -37.8684
Bassian PPB20   144.8881    -37.86859
Bassian PPB64   144.88875   -37.86946
Bassian PPB18   144.83947   -37.87174
Bassian PPB19   144.9044    -37.87285
Bassian PPB10   144.98273   -37.89712
Bassian PPB50   144.9807    -37.90846
Bassian PPB49   144.98252   -37.91762
Bassian PPB13   144.79505   -37.92617
Bassian PPB17   144.70294   -37.97092
Bassian PPB11   145.02831   -37.99153
Bassian PPB15   145.02939   -37.99492
Bassian PPB51   144.58116   -38.02771
Bassian PPB62   144.59  -38.02816
Bassian PPB31   144.46647   -38.08578
Bassian PPB32   144.44411   -38.09244
Bassian PPB30   144.43913   -38.09589
Bassian PPB7    144.65227   -38.11053
Bassian PPB16   144.68333   -38.11666
Bassian PPB26   144.7099    -38.132533
Bassian PPB23   144.713016  -38.13846
Bassian PPB37   144.71455   -38.13935
Bassian PPB34   144.72336   -38.14875
Bassian PPB54   144.720433  -38.15652
Bassian PPB12   145.087905  -38.1627416
Bassian PPB25   144.721645  -38.17019
Bassian PPB8    144.721645  -38.17019
Bassian PPB63   145.03191   -38.21439
Bassian PPB48   145.02521   -38.22641
Bassian PPB29   144.66175   -38.274116
Bassian PPB5    144.64918   -38.27462
Bassian PPH-S5  144.6554948 -38.27528186
Bassian PPH-S12 144.6976173 -38.27670215
Bassian PPB3    144.622383  -38.276816
Bassian PPB24   144.62365   -38.277716
Bassian PPB45   144.619716  -38.27935
Bassian PPB47   144.62195   -38.28
Bassian PPH-S6  144.62507   -38.28017
Bassian PPH-S16 144.63434   -38.28302
Bassian PPH-S17 144.6365326 -38.28473282
Bassian PPH-S11 144.6275046 -38.28536952
Bassian PPB4    144.61822   -38.28583
Bassian PPH-S9  144.6296328 -38.28636769
Bassian PPH-S7  144.6199981 -38.2873349
Bassian PPB46   144.594116  -38.288816
Bassian PPH-S10 144.62258   -38.29012
Bassian PPB35   144.615783  -38.2918
Bassian PPB44   144.6173    -38.2941
Bassian PPB43   144.62738   -38.29448
Bassian PPB66   144.615033  -38.29533
Bassian HMASCAN 144.532359  -38.296239
```

Comment: Please, provide DF.map or a subset of it.

Comment: You could provide some of the correct and misplaced points as a data.frame to work with. But in general, I would say there is an issue with points/DF.map than with ggplot/ggmap in your case. Otherwise there won't/shouldn't be some misplaced and some correct points.

Comment: Thanks so far. I have provided a subset of the dataframe. When I plot the points in an online visualisation tool (http://www.gpsvisualizer.com/map_input?form=data), the points hug the coastlines appropriately so it must be something to do with my map projection I'm assuming?

Comment: Ok so I have kinda figured it out. This issue only occurs when I try to plot points on say, the whole east coast of Australia, but when I make smaller, more localised maps the points plot where they should. Is there an alternative mapping method that would help me avoid this issue at large spatial scales?

Comment: @MatthewHolland Have you tried base map options other than Staten Map? Based on the data subset provided, Google Map's result aligned properly in my case, while Staten did not. May have something to do with the way the raster maps were rendered...

Comment: @Z.Lin that is very strange. I tried Google maps instead with the full extent of the dataframe and it still didn't align but when I look at large scale maps it does. Very confusing still!